# Why does the "Active" link not work?

Tags: support

Sometimes the link by the "Active" stat doesn't go anywhere. I'm talking about the highlighted text here:

[image: Active Today?]

It goes to that page with `?lastactivity` in the URL, which then redirects directly to the post that was last active, and it gets highlighted. But sometimes it just loads the page at the top and doesn't highlight anything.

Then, scanning through the posts and comments, I can't find anything that was created, edited, or changed "Today" like it says.

This happens a lot, but isn't only on C.SE. Is there something I don't understand about this link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can happen if the activity was a new answer that was then deleted.  If you don't have enough reputation to see deleted posts, that will look like a random bump to you (also on the front page).

Comment: Okay, it seems to happen pretty often, but whatever -- sounds plausible. Thanks!